# If logged in to an online app, should the main site url lead to the sign-up/in page or directly to the app?

Tags: urls

For example, if logged in to Workflowy, workflowy.com leads you straight to the app.

On the other hand, if logged in to Asana, asana.com leads you to the home page regardless. Clicking "Log In" logs you in without verification. Also, app.asana.com leads you straight to the app page.

Is there a reason to prefer one of over the other? What are some advantages of one over the other, short of the extra step to reach, respectively, the homepage or app.

Comment: If the "log in" link is there, that means that you are NOT logged in. The fact that it doesn't ask you for credentials is because it knows it is you (by cookies for example) and THEN logs you in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that there's no reason to require a logged-in user to click a login button - they should be presented with the app straight away.  If there's content on the non-logged in home page that you think might be useful to logged-in users (e.g. product news?), that should be incorporated into the app.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the distinction is because: you would like to say 'Ah well, while you are here, let me present you our Home (or whatever page, preferably with a **news update**) and then lead you on to the app (or whatever you wanted in the first place).

Just note that if the Home is a static page that the user is only too familiar with and has nothing new from time to time, it would only end up as an irritant, though.